# Scipy/Numpy: Apply cmap to actual data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to segment some DICOM images, and was trying to see if it was possible to apply a cmap filter on the actual numpy arrays

[image]

The left image is my goal, the right is what I currently have

I am able to get the left image by applying `imshow(image, cmap='nipy_spectral')`
but that doesn't change the actual numpy array on the right.

How would I go about actually applying `cmap=nipy_spectral` so it would actually transform the image on the right

Thanks

Comment: @tom10 Does calling anything in imshow actually alter the element being rendered within imshow? I haven't been able to actually alter the element with imshow calls

Comment: I removed my comment because it's confusing the issue. Sorry about that. Overall, i don't understand your question. Basically, whenever you use the word "actual(ly)" I don't know what you're referring to. There's a 2D numpy array of floats, and there's a 2D image with R, G, and B values for each point that's made by matplotlib, and this mapping is done with your cmap. Are you saying you want a numpy array with RGB values corresponding to the image produced using the `cmap`?

Comment: @tom10 Sorry, I'm having a hard time explaining what I'm going for but you got it. Cmap seems to just apply a filter without changing the actual data, I would like to have the tangible numpy array equivalent to what imshow(image, cmap='nipy_spectral') does

Answer (score 0):

The colormap functions will accept greyscale and return rgb, which I believe is what you're after.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage.data import coins

coins().shape
>>> (303, 384)

rgb = plt.cm.nipy_spectral(coins())
rgb.shape
>>> (303, 384, 4) # now an RGBA array
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else is looking, I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72664090/matplotlib-applying-cmap-directly-is-different-than-imshow).

You can simply apply a cmap on the numpy array as follows:

colormap=plt.cm.gray

colormapped_image = colormap(image).

But as stated in the link you have to apply normalization to the image beforehand.