# Matplotlib : Applying cmap directly is different than imshow()

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I have a single band image with dimensions (62, 62), that ranges from [0, 0.3]. For context it is the NDVI band, calculated by (NVI-Red) / (NVI+Red), where NVI is a band. Can more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_difference_vegetation_index

I display my image with cmap=RdYlGn to get:

[image]

However, now I want to apply the `cmap` to `ndvi` and save it to a new Numpy array. But when I do so, the image display is much different.

[image]

How can I apply the `cmap.RdYlGn` to an image and save the results such that when displaying it shows up the same as when I apply the `cmap` in `imshow`?

Comment: @JohanC , what you just wrote works to make the images the same when displaying. Thank you. If you answer with that I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [colormap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) works on inputs from `0` for the lowest color to `1` for the highest. If your input has another range, you can use explicit [normalization](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=ndvi.min(), vmax=ndvi.max())
t = cm(norm(ndvi))
plt.imshow(t)
```

to get the same conversion as used in `plt.imshow(nvdi, cmap=cm)`.